# is it bad practice to execute multiple queries in a model's method?

Tags: mysql, model, server-side

So I have a 'create user' method that does the typical items you would expect. However, I want to do another query with the primary key id that is returned from this initial insert query. This would involve a second query.

Is this bad practice? I try to minimize the queries needed, but at the moment I can't think of a better way.

Am I over thinking this? Or is there an alternative I am missing?

Comment: Create user method should create user, not less, not more.

Comment: The next query is part of creating the user. I am adding a hash of the primary key for each user so I can do urls like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdwQntqI-ts. That is why I need the id of the new user so I can make the unique hash.

Comment: Just do it. There's nothing wrong about using 2 queries